# Converting Lua function to C#

Tags: c#, lua

I've been trying to rack my brain around how I create this function call that I have no problems writing in Lua but I'm converting stuff over to C# to leave Lua and head over to something new. Much appreciated for any help I can get, I've attached the working Lua code and as far as I've got it in C#, I've also added a comment to the part of the code I can't figure out.

Lua CODE:

```
Progress({
    name = "unique_action_name",
    duration = 1000,
    label = 'Doing Something',
    useWhileDead = true,
    canCancel = true,
    controlDisables = {
        disableMovement = true,
        disableCarMovement = true,
        disableMouse = false,
        disableCombat = true,
    },
    animation = {
        animDict = "missheistdockssetup1clipboard@base",
        anim = "base",
        flags = 49,
    },
    prop = {
        model = "p_amb_clipboard_01",
        bone = 18905,
        coords = { x = 0.10, y = 0.02, z = 0.08 },
        rotation = { x = -80.0, y = 0.0, z = 0.0 },
    },
    propTwo = {
        model = "prop_pencil_01",
        bone = 58866,
        coords = { x = 0.12, y = 0.0, z = 0.001 },
        rotation = { x = -150.0, y = 0.0, z = 0.0 },
    },
}, function(cancelled)
    if not cancelled then
        -- Do Something If Action Wasn't Cancelled
    else
        -- Do Something If Action Was Cancelled
    end
end)
```

So far I've got the C# code to this

```
Progress(new {
    name = "unique_action_name",
    duration = 1000,
    label = "Doing Something",
    useWhileDead = true,
    canCancel = true,
    controlDisables = new {
        disableMovement = true,
        disableCarMovement = true,
        disableMouse = false,
        disableCombat = true,
    },
    animation = new {
        animDict = "missheistdockssetup1clipboard@base",
        anim = "base",
        flags = 49,
    },
    prop = new {
        model = "p_amb_clipboard_01",
        bone = 18905,
        coords = new { x = 0.10, y = 0.02, z = 0.08 },
        rotation = new { x = -80.0, y = 0.0, z = 0.0 },
    },
    propTwo = new {
        model = "prop_pencil_01",
        bone = 58866,
        coords = new { x = 0.12, y = 0.0, z = 0.001 },
        rotation = new { x = -150.0, y = 0.0, z = 0.0 },
    },
}, function(cancelled) { // < This part here is the question that rises for me, no clue how to call this in C#

    if (!cancelled)
        //Do Something If Action Wasn't Cancelled
    else
        // Do Something If Action Was Cancelled
});
```

Comment: What is `Progress` ? Can't you just use/write your own class ?

Comment: Progress belongs to a 3rd party script, the function call it's doing at the end is pretty common in many-core functions in the game which is the part I'm trying to learn how I can call. Not exactly sure how I can declare the callback function from the first call

Comment: Give a try to `(cancelled) => { /*  your code goes there */ }` instead of `function(canceled {  })`. This is called a [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions)

Comment: What you want to use is probably a function/action delegate. Check out the documentation for function delegates [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=netframework-4.8) and for action delegates [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: The second way you wrote it in your edit, should be working. However, **don't edit your question adding your solution** instead, you can test it, and then, if it's working as expected, post it as an answer

Comment: Sorry kinda new to StackOverflow, the comment you gave me with the lambada expression gives me this error `Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation without first casting it to a delegate or expression tree type` I will go ahead and test mine in just a few minutes but your way would solve it so much better than writing a bunch of functions for each call back :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with help from the comments above, I really appreciate all of your help!

```
Progress(new
{
    name = "unique_action_name",
    duration = 1000,
    label = "Doing Something",
    useWhileDead = true,
    canCancel = true,
    controlDisables = new
    {
        disableMovement = true,
        disableCarMovement = true,
        disableMouse = false,
        disableCombat = true,
    },
    animation = new
    {
        animDict = "missheistdockssetup1clipboard@base",
        anim = "base",
        flags = 49,
    },
    prop = new
    {
        model = "p_amb_clipboard_01",
        bone = 18905,
        coords = new { x = 0.10, y = 0.02, z = 0.08 },
        rotation = new { x = -80.0, y = 0.0, z = 0.0 },
    },
    propTwo = new
    {
        model = "prop_pencil_01",
        bone = 58866,
        coords = new { x = 0.12, y = 0.0, z = 0.001 },
        rotation = new { x = -150.0, y = 0.0, z = 0.0 },
    },
}, new Action<bool>((isCanceled) =>
{
    if (!isCanceled)
        Debug.WriteLine("DONE");
    else
        Debug.WriteLine("CANCELED");
}));
```